# Codeigniter route not working for some links

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My main concern is what i'm missing here. The route worked perfectly for what i've tested, after i started to add content on the website it stopped working

```
$route['projects/view/([A-Za-z0-9])/task/([A-Za-z0-9])'] = 'Projects/view_project_task/$1/$2';
```

Function in model is defined like:

```
public function view_project_task($project_id, $project_task_id)
```

If i access it like http://mydomain/projects/view_project_task/1/8 is working perfectly fine, if i try to access like http://mydomain/projects/view/1/task/8 i get a 404 error on some linkes and it works on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try using callbacks in your route?

```
$route['projects/(.+)'] = function ($params)
    {
            $return = explode('/', $params);
            //here you need to count how many params has to know if your url
            //is like 1/8 -> [0]=>view_project_task [1]=>1 [2]=>8 
            //or like 1/task/8 [0]=>view [1]=>1 [2]=>task [3]=>8
            return 'projects/view_project_task/' . strlower($return[1]) . '/' . ( count($return > 3)) ? $return[3] : $return[2];
    };
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll test it today and come back with feedback

Comment: hi, i forgot add some conditions you has, check the answer i edited